# Finding an Example of a continuous function that is not continuous at any point of its subset

Tags: general-topology

Let X and Y be topological spaces. Let f : X → Y be a function and
A ⊂ X. Provide an example showing that f|A is continuous but that
f is not continuous at any point of A. Make sure to justify why your
example satisfies the desired criteria

By looking at the question, I understand that the function f as a map from the whole domain X to Y is supposed to be discontinuous at the points of A.However when the domain is restricted to A itself, it is continuous. This is confusing me

Any hints please?

Thank you

Comment: Hint: characteristic function of the rationals on $[0, 1]$.

Comment: This is a little simpler than Jacky's suggestion: take $A = \{a\}$ to be a singleton set. Any function $h$ on $A$ is continuous, but that doesn't tell you anything about the continuity at $a$ of an extension of $h$ to all of $X$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f:[0,1]\to [0,1]$, $f(x) = \chi_{\mathbb{Q}} $. Then $f\bigg|_{\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]}$ is continuous (constant function), but $f$ is not continuous at any point in $[0,1]\cap \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: I am not sure what f(x) = χQ means. Is there another simpler example?

Comment: In general, $\chi_A$ is the indicator function on the set $A$, defined by $f(x) =1$ if $x \in A$ and $0$ if $x \not \in A$. So in this case, $\chi_\mathbb{Q}(x)$ returns 1 if $x$ is rational and $0$ if $x$ is irrational. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function